# Open a gz file using Minizip Library

Tags: gzip

I'm trying to open a gz file with Minizip library (built on zlib).

Here is the code:

```
......
......

unzFile uf = unzOpen("MyFile.gz");

......
```

But Visual Studio 2013 crashes with this message:

Debug Assertion Failed!
file open.c
line 98

Expression: ("Invalid file open mode",0)

What could it mean?

Answer (score 1):

A `.gz` file is a single file that's been compressed.

A `.zip` file is a compressed archive; i.e. a hierarchical structure of compressed files.

**tl;dr** minizip doesn't support `.gz` files as it's not a `.zip` file.

Comment: I solved the problem writing

     `gzFile gz = gzopen("MyFile.gz");`

Now, how can I "get" its content (MyFile)?

Comment: Ask a new question.  I certainly won't be helping you though.